# Three.js line rendering error

Tags: javascript, line, three.js

I am trying to render a Line which is positioned on top of a basic Mesh. It works fine if i just view it from above but failes to render if the scene gets rotated in some ways as shown in the following picture:
[Linkt to picture](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1424069/28998/ec6e60d4-4d11-11e2-9b9a-b804bd2c9439.png)

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Greetings,
Dennis

Comment: You're using CanvasRenderer, right?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the CanvasRenderer.

Comment: Anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render it in two passes.

```
// on init
renderer.autoClear = false;

// on update
renderer.clear();
renderer.render( sceneFloor, camera );
renderer.render( sceneLine, camera );
```